# C++: calling member functions within constructor?

Tags: c++

The following code raises a runtime error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <ext/slist>

class IntList :  public __gnu_cxx::slist<int> {
public:
    IntList() { tail_ = begin(); } // seems that there is a problem here
    void append(const int node) { tail_ = insert_after(tail_, node); }

private:
    iterator tail_;
};

int main() {
    IntList list;

    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);

    for (IntList::iterator i = list.begin(); i != list.end(); ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Seems that the problem is in the constructor `IntList()`. Is it because it calls the member function `begin()`?

Comment: Why are you typedefing `iterator` to itself?  And, if this `slist` is based off of the STL `slist` then it doesn't have a virtual destructor, so you probably shouldn't derive from it publicly (or at all).

Comment: Sorry. the typedef is a mistake. I have modified it.

Comment: For me the problem is the append(). Have you compiled with the -g flag. Also it probably help to add print statements to see where it crashes

Comment: @James and poerboy. Technically yes. But not really relevant to the question.

Comment: @James: thanks! Learned another new things!

Comment: @James McNellis: Its very standard to typedef types from inherited classes like that. Look at the definition of nearly every container in the STL.

Comment: @Martin:  It was unusual in this case, because `slist<T>::iterator` is a public typedef, so it was wholly unnecessary.  If a public base has a public typedef, there's no reason to redeclare it in the derived class.  As for my comment not being relevant to the question, that's why I posted it as a comment and not an answer.  Using comments for questions or advice (e.g., don't derive from a class that doesn't have a virtual destructor) is common practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like You are inserting after end();

In the body of the constructor

```
IntList() { tail_ = begin(); }
```

the base class is constructed and it's members can be called, but for an empty list, it should return end();

Comment: This looks right; the iterator passed to `insert_after()` must be dereferenceable, and `end()` is not.

Comment: So, I want to add the private member tail_ to track the tail of the list so that I can append elements faster. How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't derive from `slist`, to begin with. But to solve that particular problem try calling `insert()` instead.

Comment: Thx WilhelmTell! Maybe I should use slist as the underlying container of my list, the same way as how <stack> is based on <deque>

Comment: @powerboy yes, that makes more sense. either bring an `slist` object into `IntList` as a data-member, or derive privately from `slist`. The problem is there only when clients try to create a polymorphic object of `IntList`, like so: `slist* l = new IntList();` and sometime later `delete l;`. When that happens the `slist` part of `IntList` will clean up properly, but the `IntList` won't: it will result in undefined behaviour. If you don't derive publicly from `slist` then users simply can't make a polymorophic object of the concrete `IntList` type, so it's safe.

Comment: @powerboy if you derive privately from `slist` then remember that inside your class you still have access to `slist`. that means that any member (or friend) of your class can still create and delete a polymorphic type that interfaces on `slist`. In other words, _you_ can still shoot yourself in the foot. For this reason it's a bad idea to derive in any way from a class that has no virtual destructor. But yes, you'd still limit the problem to you shooting yourself in the foot, rather than anyone at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not in the constructor but in the first call to `append()`. Because your list is empty `begin()` equals `end()`. `end()` is a valid iterator, but the one after that isn't. To solve that particular problem try calling `insert()` instead.

That said, a fast peek at `<ext/slist>` confirms that the destructor of `slist` isn't virtual, which means `slist` wasn't intended to be derived from.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for slist<> indicates that the iterator provided to insert_after must be dereferenceable.

Since your list is empty the begin() returns end() and is thus not dereferenceable.

See documentation here:

```
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Slist.html
```

> iterator insert_after(iterator pos, const value_type& x)
>
> pos must be a dereferenceable iterator in *this. (That is, pos may not be end().) Inserts a copy of x immediately following pos. The return value is an iterator that points to the new element. Complexity: constant time.

Answer (score 0):

.begin() is invalid if there are no elements in your collection.

Comment: `begin()` is always valid on a container.  If there are no elements in the container, then `begin() == end()` (assuming this GNU extension slist is an implementation of the STL slist, of course).

Comment: Learn something new everyday, I guess.  :-)