# Is it bad form to call an instance method from within that instance's __init__ method?

Tags: python, methods, initialization

I'm building an object that has an attribute whose value is randomly generated at instantiation. The attribute will be assigned a new value (also randomly) from time to time, so I'm defining a method to do so. Is it bad form to initialize the attribute by calling that method from within `__init__`? It would be easy enough to avoid—I'd just have to duplicate a small amount of code—but it seems more elegant to call the method. Here's an example:

```
import random

class Robot(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.setDirection()

    def setDirection(self):
        self.direction = random.random() * 360
```

Comment: No, it is not bad form to do so. The method (setDirection) is a function to help the class, if it needs to help the class fulfill its purpose during init or any other stage.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091833/calling-member-functions-from-a-constructor

Comment: There's a chance of getting bugs due to things being initialised in a different order than you expect, but as long as the helper method doesn't depend on any state of the object you should be fine.

Comment: (An example of the above would be if you call a method overriden in the subclass from the `__init__` method of the superclass. Since the superclass constructor is usually called first, if the override assumes that the code in the subclass constructor has run you have a problem that's somewhat fiddly to resolve. Albeit less so in Python than in Java/C# because you can call `super().__init__()` whenever.)

Comment: @ millimoose That's a good point, and I was unsure about doing this because I'm used to seeing attributes defined/initialized directly in `__init__`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's fine to call instance methods within `__init__`, but be careful if they might be overridden in subclasses:

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.greet()

    def greet(self):
        print('Hello from A')


class B(A):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        self.name = name

    def greet(self):
        print('Hello from B', self.name)
```

Now if B is instantiated, `B.greet` is called by `A.__init__` before its preconditions are satisfied (`self.name` is not defined).

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing wrong with calling other instance methods within `__init__`.

---

Note that in python there is a distinction between *instance methods* and [*class methods*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod).  I can't think of a good reason to use a *class method* within `__init__` -- which isn't to say that a good reason doesn't exist, but that the cases are probably pretty rare.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll edit the title to reflect this (hope I get it right).