# generic class partial initializer

Tags: typescript, object-initializers

I have a lot of similar classes that I'd like to initialize with the following syntax:

```js
class A {
    b: number = 1
    constructor(initializer?: Partial<A>) {
        Object.assign(this, initializer)
    }
}

new A({b: 2})
```

I think that being able to get initialized by such means is a generic behaviour and so I'd like to isolate this logic to avoid repeating myself in douzens of files. I tried this:

```js
class Initializable<T> {
    constructor(initializer?: Partial<T>) {
        Object.assign(this, initializer)
    }
}

class A extends Initializable<A> {
    b: number = 1
}

new A({b: 2})
```

This compiles but doesn't work because the implicit `super()` goes first so `b` gets `2` as wanted but then gets `1`.

Does TypeScript offers a type-safe solution to get this behaviour in all my classes?

Comment: Not a solution, but very relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595943/why-are-derived-class-property-values-not-seen-in-the-base-class-constructor/43595944).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to run something from the base class after the derived class constructor has finished. The only solution I can see (and I invite others to come up with a better one :) ) is to use a function which augments what will become the `A` class instead of using a base class. Basically the mixin approach to adding functionality.

```
function initializable<T extends new() => any>(cls: T) : {
    new (data?: Partial<InstanceType<T>>) : InstanceType<T> // add the constructor
} & Pick<T, keyof T> /* add statics back */ {
    return class extends (cls as any) {
        constructor(data?: Partial<InstanceType<T>>){
            super();
            if(data) { 
                Object.assign(this, data);
            }
        }
    } as any

}

const A = initializable(class {
    b: number = 2;
    static staticMethod() { }
    method() {}
});
type A = InstanceType<typeof A> // Optionally define the type for A to have the same effect as the class

var a = new A({b:1});
console.log(a.b) // output 1
a.method();
A.staticMethod();
a = new A();
console.log(a.b) // output 2
var aErr = new A({b:"1"}); //error
```

**Note** Mix-in usually are not allowed not to change the constructor arguments and this is why we have to massage the types a little but it works out.

Comment: I don't understand all this code at the moment so I'll so my searching but it is very simple to use and seems to work as I wished. I thought about modifying the class but I believed one couldn't without losing its type signatures. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yovar you are welcome, If you have any questions don't hesitate to ask :)