# Parent method not accessible in the children instance after translation to JavaScript from TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, ecmascript-6, tsc

I've got the following TypeScript classes:

```
class AnyBackendRoute {
   public getProps() {...}
}
```

```
class AnyBFFRoute extends AnyBackendRoute {
   public getProps() {...}
}
```

```
class UserSignUpRoute extends AnyBFFRoute {
   public getSomethingElse() {...}
}
```

I transpile them to commonJS-ES6 and include them in another file (.js).

In the original code (in test file, before transpilation) I can easily do:

```
const route = new UserSignUpRoute()

// getProps() visible from AnyBFFRoute as it's a public method
console.log(route.getProps())
```

but when I try the same thing with the transpiled code (that contains also .d.ts file), I am getting a TypeScript error:

`Type 'UserSignUpRoute' is missing the following properties from type 'AnyBFFRoute': getProps`

In the transpiled code I would expect to find something like:

```
UserSignUpRoute.prototype.getProps = function () {
    return this.props;
};
```

but it's not there! Same, in the appropriate `.d.ts` file. I cannot see `getProps()` method from the parent class but only the local public methods.

Am I wrong to think those methods should be available in the *UserSignUpRoute.js* as well?

If so, why there is an inconsistency so that I can call `route.getProps()` in the pre-transpiled code and not afterwards?

Comment: Here are links to a few interesting reading material on this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595943/why-are-derived-class-property-values-not-seen-in-the-base-class-constructor

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1617

Comment: `UserSignUpRoute.prototype.getProps` would only be there if you're targetting pre-ES2015.

Comment: so would it be a good practice to repeat: `public getProps() {return super.getProps()}` to achieve the visibility?